# Regex: match from start of string, but not including nth occurrence

Tags: regex

Im looking to get everything to the left of nth occurrence. Currently I have:

```
"Hello, World"

(?:[^o]*o){2}

>> yields Hello, Wo
```

I want to exclude the the search character. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What regex engine?

Comment: Use `(?:[^o]*o){n-1}[^o]*`, so here, `[^o]*o[^o]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perhaps a `(?=o)` at the end to meet the nth occurrence requirement?

Comment: @NetMage That is usually not required as in such situations, people usually match till a char or end of string. If there MUST be the nth char, then yes, `(?=o)` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks guys much appreciated, Wiktor's solution worked

Comment: @NetMage Im not sure which engine, its through a platform maybe using a subset supported by Java.

Comment: :"([^"]*)"[^"]*